# Using the New List command with a Passed Parameter

Tags: vb.net, list, filestream

I'm trying to Pass a Field Parameter from my form textbox to a Function to create a New List object from the Data Table parameter I'm passing.

In the following code, the first tmpReadTable shows with no syntax error, but when I try to use the Parm with the Datatable name I'm not sure what I'm missing syntax wise. I'm new to this, thanks in advance!

### Updated code below:

Thank you for all the helpful replies...sorry I'm not more experienced, I'm coming from a Visual Foxpro background.

To summarize:

1. I want to pass in my IMPORT table parameters from my form.
2. The cImportTable is an empty SQL Table to use to import and validate each CSV file row.
3. I found this example in Murach's VB book but he leaves out how the LIST is being created from a PRODUCTS table in an earlier exercise. So I thought I could just substitute my passed cImportTable to do the same...that's where I'm stuck and maybe you all know of a better way.

   Private Function ReadImportFile(ByVal cImportFile As String, ByVal cGroupID As String, ByVal cControlTable As String, ByVal cImportTable As String)

   ```
   MessageBox.Show(cImportFile + "  " + cGroupID + "  " + cControlTable)

   If Not File.Exists(cImportFile) Then
       MessageBox.Show("File: " + cImportFile + " does not exist - cancelling process.")
       Return False
   End If

   Dim curFileStream As New StreamReader(New FileStream(cImportFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))

   Dim curImportTable = "NewDataSet." + cImportTable

   'Here I'm trying to create a LIST or DATASET using my Empty SQL Import Table and read in each row of the CSV file in the DO WHILE loop
   '...I'm coming from Visual Foxpro background so am not sure what I'm missing or what is the standard procedure to do this simple task.

   'This line gives me a syntax issue - and I'm not even sure what it's suppose to do, I'm taking it from Murach's VB book example, 
   'but he leaves out this vital piece of how to create this LIST from a Datatable - or if it's even the right method to use.
   Dim tmpReadTable = New List(Of curImportTable)

   Do While curFileStream.Peek <> -1
       Dim row As String = curFileStream.ReadLine
       Dim columns() As String = row.Split(",")

       Dim ImportRecord As New curImportTable
       ImportRecord.GroupId = columns(0)
       ImportRecord.MemberId = columns(1)

   Loop

   'More Processing after Importing CSV file.....

   curFileStream.Close()

   'If lNoErrors
   Return True
   ```

   End Function

Comment: What kind of file are you attempting to read?

Comment: You create a FileStream then do nothing with it but .Close it.

Comment: When you concatenate 2 strings you are pretty sure to end up with a string so why are you calling .ToString? `"NewDataSet." + cImportTable.ToString` ???

Comment: `New List(Of curImportTable)` ?? New List(Of T) where T stands for Type like a String or an Integer or a class of your own. As we just pointed out, `curImportTable` is most certainly a String variable not a Type.

Comment: And another thing, a Function should have a return type. In this case, `As Boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable instead of `TYPE` on the code line #3 here

```
' This seems to be ok, no syntax error
Dim tmpReadTable = New List(Of NewDataSet.FO_ImportDataTable)

' The variable below implicitely will be of STRING type
Dim curImportTable = "NewDataSet." + cImportTable.ToString
' This line is not going to work
Dim tmpReadTable = New List(Of curImportTable)
' BUT THIS WILL
Dim x = New List(Of String)
```

Another issue is that `Dim tmpReadTable` happened twice in your code! can't re-declare variable. On top you declared it as `NewDataSet.FO_ImportDataTable`

Besides, I recommend declare all variables like `Dim curImportTable as String`, this way you can recognize types easier. `Option Infer` is good when you use anonymous types, LINQ, etc

Comment: `Dim tmpReadTable happened twice in your code!`  I think that was meant as these are the two different things they tried.

Comment: @LarsTech I see what you saying and yet, in the presented code it does happens twice. If I pretend it happens once the problem is at `New List(Of curImportTable)`

Comment: Ok, so I made a few changes, but am still missing the all important line of code to create this LIST or DATASET to read in the CSV file, row by row...sorry I'm not more experience in trying to communicate, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @JeffreyClarke I already posted in my answer about this `Dim tmpReadTable = New List(Of curImportTable)`. This is incorrect. See answer above. Your question should not be about multiple issues. If you have problems reading CSV file, there are plenty of answers how to do it. My answer is strictly whats wrong in your code. If you will keep changing the question, it will be impossible to answer this. Thanks